# How can I get that dict data (qrtools python)

Tags: python-3.x

How can I get that data? Without that lambda and it must return data not <function ...>
[trying to get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqoSM.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code or values when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Here try This!

```
from qrtools import QR
image = QR(filename="blabla.png")
if image.decode():
  print image.data
  print image.data_type
  print image.data_to_string()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?